# Short story where a human ship crashes on the alien planet and alien kids brought the humans to their home and hide in stable

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story long back. It was a small town and two people were expecting alien visitors for business contract. The alien ship crashes and the little kids of these two people brought the aliens home, hide them from their parents and feed them.

In the end, it was revealed that aliens were actually humans and the kids were alien kids. The planet was not Earth.

Comment: When was "long back?"  2 years ago?  10?  50?  Was it online, in an anthology, or a magazine?

Comment: I agree, this sounds like "Youth"

Comment: Yes, Asimov's "Youth" is correct. I have written the answer also for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story is *Youth* by *Asimov*. It was published in the May 1952 edition of Space Science Fiction magazine.

**Links:**

1. It's available at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Space_Science_Fiction_v01n01_1952-05_cape1736/page/n68/mode/1up) - PDF format of entire May 1952 edition.
2. [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31547/31547-h/31547-h.htm) - HTML format

References:

1. Comment by @user14111

Comment: Wow! Someone downvoted my answer without giving any reason. Anyone has any clue what's wrong with this answer?