# Short story where the 'humans' are revealed to be tentacled aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

So I'm trying to find the name of a short story that I read as a child. I'm pretty sure that it was written by Ray Bradbury and it was part of an anthology.

It has a very surprising twist at the end. It's about some humans living on a planet. I don't even know what it was about, but at the end we find out that these weren't actually humans, but some sort of monsters/aliens with tentacles or something.

The big reveal was right at the end, and the monsters really thought they were humans.

LE: I'm pretty sure it was from Martian Chronicles, but I can't find it for the life of me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Thank you! More than 20 years ago, I think, so about 1995, give or take.

Comment: That's actually closer to 30 years, but I'm pretty sure my internal clock is telling me the 90's were only about 10 years ago!

Comment: This resembles a "Future Shocks" story from about early eighties (2000AD). Sure it wasn't an old comic you picked up?

Comment: Reminds me of [Youth](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31547/31547-h/31547-h.htm) by Isaac Asimov.  If so, this would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253002/short-story-where-a-human-ship-crashes-on-the-alien-planet-and-alien-kids-brough

Comment: @DoscoJones: my man! you saved my ass. cheers!

Comment: I feel like there are multiple Goosebumps books where this (or something similar) is the twist ending. (My Best Friend Is Invisible, The Girl Who Cried Monster, Welcome to Camp Nightmare, My Hairiest Adventure, A Shocker on Shock Street, The Blob That Ate Everyone...)

Comment: John Kippax did something along similar lines in "The Underlings in New Worlds #62. The aliens think that Terrans have come among them, and an alien actually falls in love with a "Terran" and is horrified when he finds her communicating with a real one, who appears monstrous to him. She is in fact a multiple aptitudes robot, designed to look like an alien

Comment: There is a "Martian Chronicles" story that sort of matches your description. ["The Million Years Picnic"](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?504661) ([pdf](https://lasp.colorado.edu/mop/files/2019/08/million-year-picnic.pdf)) is about a family that emigrates from Earth to Mars. The kids want to see some Martians. Finally the parents show the kids their reflection and say "There they are". The point is that the human family are Martians now because that's where they'll live.